# Binding combo-box with default text using Reader

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combo box which populate the data which comes from the database. I want default text like
"Please Select" to appear on the combo box when you first load the page and also when you reset it must be on top. default text is appearing when you only opens the combo box. Please help

here is how i am binding my combo box;

```
    private void LoadCombo()
    {
        try
        {
            oConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
            oCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from tbldpt", oConnection);
            oAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(oCommand);
            oConnection.Open();
            oDataset = new System.Data.DataSet();
            SqlDataReader oReader = oCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (oReader.Read())
            {                   
                string _Combobox = oReader["Name"].ToString();
                cboDepartment.Items.Add(_Combobox);
            }
            cboDepartment.Items.Insert(0, "--Select Department--");
            oReader.Close();
            oConnection.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }

    }
```

Comment: How/where did you call this `LoadCombo` method?

Comment: public UserList()
        {
            LoadCombo();
        }

Comment: After insertion of default text just call cboDepartment.SelectedIndex = 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet,

```
cboDepartment.Items.Add("--Select Department--");
 while (oReader.Read())
  {                   
    string _Combobox = oReader["Name"].ToString();
    cboDepartment.Items.Add(_Combobox);
  }
  cboDepartment.selectedIndex=0;
```

Comment: Thanks it works the way i wanted it to work. One last thing, do you have an idea why i am getting this error when trying to convert int to string ;

here is my line of codding...

error : "Input was not in the correct format"
 int userid = int.Parse(i.SubItems[3].Text);

Comment: is for listview control when binding 4 items

Answer (score 0):

Create List of string and bind with your Combo box.

```
try
        {
            oConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
            oCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from tbldpt", oConnection);
            oConnection.Open();
            oDataset = new System.Data.DataSet();
            SqlDataReader oReader = oCommand.ExecuteReader();

            list<string> _combobox=new list<string>();
            _combobox.add("--Select Department--");

            while (oReader.Read())
            {                   
                _combobox.Add(oReader["Name"].ToString());

            }
cboDepartment.Datasource=_combobox

            oReader.Close();
            oConnection.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
```